# How to use createjs in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, createjs

I'm wanting to import createjs into my reactjs app.
The createjs file i have is from https://code.createjs.com/

Im trying to import in my App.js file as
`import './lib/createjs.min';`

However I get the error 'createjs' is no defined error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add script tag for createjs in the index.html under public directory so that you can access the createjs globally instead of imported it in different places.

```
<script src="https://code.createjs.com/1.0.0/createjs.min.js"></script>
```

You cannot import it like you have given.